# What is the correct way to show menu / help screens in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, menu

When using tools like Org-mode and Magit the mode will sometimes show help menus.  For instance, org-mode export will show a nice menu that accept single keys and then executes some command.  In Magit, when looking at the status view it will accept tabs to expand the staged and commit areas.

These areas, for both Git and Org, are nicely placed to take up some portion of the emacs frame that is mostly convenient.  How does emacs do choose this?

Additionally, these views are read-only, up until the user presses tab in the case of Magit and the status view.  Is there a best practice when creating these views which control editing, but allows the mode to edit the file and present alternative text?

Perhaps the answer is take a look at these function A, B, and C.  Which is fine, I'm just learning and experimenting on my own.

Comment: Please narrow your question down to just one specific issue that has a finite amount of correct answers.  Each help window that you see in a variety of different major-modes may have a different method of generation and display, and there is not one general answer or best practice -- the question is too broad to be answered as is.

Comment: @lawlist I'd love to -- having trouble deciding the best way without making it even more broad.  For instance, if you were making a new mode that you knew you wanted to behave a lot like Magit, and also use the tab-cycling of org-mode how would you start?  I don't really know where to start.  I'm fumbling in the dark a bit until I feel it worth putting it up on stack-overflow.

Comment: One idea you may wish to consider exploring is `narrow-to-region` to work on a specific task.  You may also wish to consider exploring an `indirect-buffer` (populated by first using `narrow-to-region`), which can have it's own mode and its own keybindings or it can keep the previous mode stuff active.  I do this when editing a task from either the `*Org Agenda*` buffer or from the master to-do file.  Have a look at `org-narrow-to-subtree` -- I use a variation of that with `make-indirect-buffer`.  For example, my main to-do file has `truncate-lines` whereas my indirect buffer has `word-wrap`.

Answer (score 2):

Magit in particular is not the simplest introduction to popup buffers in Emacs, but it certainly is sophisticated and a good read.  Find `magit-popup.el` on your machine, for example <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>find-function</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>magit-popup-mode-setup</kbd>.  To me, that function looks like a good candidate to start reading that file.  You can see the macro `magit-define-popup` in use for example in `magit-push-popup` in the file `magit-remote.el`

In the end, it boils down to opening a new buffer in a new window and give it a dedicated major mode which has all the key-bindings.

Another good candidate is the family of `temp-buffer-*` functions.

Hope, that gives some pointers to start reading.

Comment: I think this is the kind of thing I was after.  Basically, I think I need to read through magit as best I can.  I was aiming at opening a new buffer and setting a custom-mode (one meant for the task) as well as customizing the key bindings.  For some reason I didn't really think I'd need more than one mode, but it does look like magit uses more than one mode too.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to show menus/help screens à la Magit and org-mode is with Hydras:

- http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Discoverability#Hydra
- https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra/
- https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra/wiki

It's a short elisp method to write and it will give you a menu like org-mode. For example:

```
(defhydra hydra-zoom (global-map "<f2>")
"zoom"
  ("g" text-scale-increase "in")
  ("l" text-scale-decrease "out"))
```

ps: it's not what org-mode and magit use. Magit's system wasn't re-usable until recently and I don't know how it compares with Hydra. A nice feature of Hydras is that you can tell it to not disappear after a keypress, so than you can press many keys in a row.